# How can i end while loop after the little red cross clicked in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a window with many buttons and labels. The problem is when I close these windows (via the little red cross) the program still working in Task Manager (i think because of the while loop that i have in my code).
in the following sample code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{


 while (true)
 {
   //do something.........
 }
}
```

so how can i sense the little red cross and finished the while loop .

Comment: There are a few ways of solving this problem, but let's start with a question: Why are you performing a long calculation inside your main thread (which will cause your GUI to freeze) instead of a separate thread?

Comment: @cmannett85 it's just an example, the while loop can be exit after 2 or 3 loops only less or more that.but the problem in how can i sense the click on the little red cross in the main window and exit all loops and threads related to the main window.

Comment: @cmannett85 can you give me one way form your ways?

Answer (score 0):

Reimplement `closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)` ([docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent)) in your main window to emit a signal or manually notify the objects containing the loops to stop.  Then inside each of the loops call `QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags flags = QEventLoop::AllEvents)` so events can be processed in the event queue even if the thread is processing in a loop, and then check the halt condition set by your close event signal.

There's undoubtedly cleaner solutions but without more specific information about your program architecture, it's hard to comment further.